# slf4j - log files getting created on one machine and not on another

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j

I am running a scala program which creates log files. My program seems to be working just fine on my linux box but when I deployed my code onto a similar linux box, I dont see any log files, there doesnt seem to be any permission issues, more so, everytime when I try to log something I see an error on the terminal,

Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong here ?

so the output looks something like the following,

```
[info] Resolving com.github.jsimone#webapp-runner;7.0.34.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 12 Scala sources and 64 Java sources to /someDir/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Running some.program
[info] In PAWS DB Service
[info] dbURI -- jdbc:sqlite:test4.db
[error] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
[error] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/someLocation/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[error] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/someLocation/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[error] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[error] SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[error] [main] INFO some.program - Starting PAWS *************************************
[info]  +++++++++++ CREATING tables ++++++++++++++++
[info] GET acquisitions/
[error] [main] INFO some.program - Running GET acquisitions/
[error] [PAWS-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO some.program.AcquisitionResourceManager -  ------  Starting AcquisitionResourceManager ------
[error] [PAWS-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO some.program.WebServicesAcqServerSubscriber - ----- Subscriber for acq ser started ------
[info] ----- Subscriber for acq ser started ------
[error] [PAWS-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO some.program.PAWebServicesBaseWriterSubscriber2 - started base writer subs 2------
[info] started base writer subs 2------
[info] prestart
[error] [PAWS-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO some.program.PostPrimaryHandler - -------------Started Job Processor ---------------------
[info]  -------------------------------------Registering dbRef with AcqManager------------------------
[error] [PAWS-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO some.program.AcquisitionResourceManager -  -------------------------------------Registering dbRef with AcqManager--------------------------
[info] class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[info] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/jna1013686264560495771.tmp which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
[info] It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
[info]  from GET activeAcquisitions ---
[info] [INFO] [03/12/2015 10:39:06.709] [primary-analysis-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://primary-analysis-actor-system/deadLetters] Message [scala.runtime.BoxedUnit] from Actor[akka://primary-analysis-actor-system/user/$a#-1910891666] to Actor[akka://primary-analysis-actor-system/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[info] 0
[info] [INFO] [03/12/2015 10:39:07.034] [primary-analysis-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://primary-analysis-actor-system/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to /0.0.0.0:8091
[info] [INFO] [03/12/2015 10:39:07.035] [primary-analysis-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://primary-analysis-actor-system/deadLetters] Message [akka.io.Tcp$Bound] from Actor[akka://primary-analysis-actor-system/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0#-434781875] to Actor[akka://primary-analysis-actor-system/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

my logback.xml file looks like, the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.out</target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>paws.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="akka" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="Slf4jLogger" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="scala.slick" level="INFO" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

will greatly appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states:

```
[error] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/someLocation/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[error] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/someLocation/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[error] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

So explicitely **exclude** `slf4j-simple` in ivy/maven/whatever-dependency-management-framework since most chances are you don't explicitly define it but it's getting brought into classpath as transient dependency.

Also described [in the url above](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings).

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, I find it strange though because, when I run this program through my ide (idea) I do see a log file it is only when I run it through sbt console or commandline I dont see the log file and some logger errors.

Comment: you shouldn't leave logging implicitly defined otherwise you'll run in classpath (who comes first) issues as above. I would suggest to be explicit. Since you are using logback as your SLF4j binding then the strategy is well defined in here: http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html (top left graph). Pay attention at the SLF4J bridge libs (log4j-over-slf4j and mcl-over-slf4j)

Comment: Got it fixed, just in case anyone else lands in the same problem as I do, Following is the solution;

libraryDependencies ++=  Seq("ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2" ,
                            "com.typesafe.scala-logging" % "scala-logging-slf4j_2.10" % "2.1.2").map(_.force())

libraryDependencies ~= {_.map(_.exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-simple"))}